# Application insights and Stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I am trying to read application insights export data using stream analytics. Here is how my blob looks like.
[image: my blob storage]

In my stream analytics I reference this blob and try to read these files using the download sample data functionality. I do not get any data.

I am also setting the PATH PREFIX PATTERN

As democenteralinsightscollector_5cc2f280d52d47bdbe186e87d8037fc0/Requests/{date}/{time}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following links will help you with the process: [http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/export-to-power-bi-from-application-insights/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-power-bi/)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was trying to do the same and was able to get Stream Analytics to read the Application Insights blob export, but where this fails is that the Json that is emitted by Application Insights has the following entries:

**"anonAcquisitionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","authAcquisitionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z**"

which causes the Stream Analytics Input to fail.

The Stream Analytics operation logs has the following:

**First Occurred: 04/30/2015 03:06:22 | Resource Name: appinsightsevents | Message: Failed to convert values to match the column type for column anonAcquisitionDate**

So, basically Stream Analytics cannot process the input